# How can I store a format string template outside of my source code?

Tags: rust, format

When translating, messages can be in different languages and have format parameters. I want to be able to do this where the template can be stored in a file:

```
static PATTERN: &'static str = r"Hello {inner};";

/// in some implementation

fn any_method(&self) -> String {
    format!(PATTERN, inner = "world");
}
```

Comment: Note that translating a program is a [problem](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/gettext.html#Concepts) [far](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0j74jcxSunY) [far](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Localization/Localization_content_best_practices) [more](https://bjoernkw.com/2013/06/30/i18n-is-a-hard-and-largely-unsolved-problem/) [complicated](https://www.factorio.com/blog/post/fff-244) than just having a few template strings.

Comment: @mcarton +20 for FFF blog post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is definitely possible and trivial to do using the [`include_str`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.include_str.html) macro that has been available in the standard library since version 1.0.0. The following example was tested with `rustc` 1.58.1:

- Contents of `src/main.rs`:

  ```rust
  println!(include_str!("src/hello-world.tmpl"), "world");
  ```
- Contents of `src/hello-world.tmpl`

  ```
  Hello {inner}
  ```

This works because `include_str` injects the contents of the template file as a string literal before `println`, `format`, and friends have a chance to evaluate their arguments. This approach only works when the format template you want to include is available during macro expansion - like it is in your example. If it's not, then you should consider other options like the ones suggested by [@DK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52015854/10126273).

As an added bonus: You can also define format strings in source code locations other than the site where they are used by defining them as macros.

Answer (score 4):

That's not possible.  Format strings must be actual literal strings.

The next best approach would be some kind of [dynamic string format](https://crates.io/search?q=dynamic%20string%20format) library.  Or, failing that, you could always use [`str::replace`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.replace) if your needs aren't too complex.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding OP's question, this is easily possible using the `include_str` macro. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72728368/10126273).